# how to switch camera recording session AVfoundation?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

i have a session to recording, but when I change the camera, this only save the firstly video from first camera, then swith not save, How can I do this?

I use this function to switch and load new camera:

```
 - (IBAction)switchCameras:(id)sender

AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;
if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)
    desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
else
    desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
    if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {
        [[previewLayer session] beginConfiguration];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
        for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[previewLayer session] inputs]) {
            [[previewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
        }
        [[previewLayer session] addInput:input];
        [[previewLayer session] commitConfiguration];
        break;
    }
}
isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible?I can show the second camera in previewLayer, but only save te first... Could be that then add a new input, the session close?

Answer (score 1):

After removing the old `AVCaptureDeviceInput` and adding the new `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, you may need to recreate your `AVCaptureConnection`, adjusting the flow from the new capture input to the capture output.